# create exit button in excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have an excel 2003 application which contains an user defined exit button.How can i implement the same in excel 2010.

```
 Set NewBtn = TBar.Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
    With NewBtn
        .Caption = "Exit Excel"
        .FaceId = 2151               ' Running Man
        .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
```

Comment: what type of button do you want to add Forms or ActiveX? Worksheet or userform?

Comment: exit and save or exit without save?

Comment: The OP is referring to a button (msoControlButton) on a toolbar. This is different from the buttons you would place on the sheet or on a form.

Comment: You will need to use the Ribbon to do what you are looking for. I suggest you add the tag "Ribbon" and "Ribbon-Control" to your questin. Also change the wording of your question to ask how to create a button on the ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

Excel 2003 allows you to create buttons on toolbars. That is the past; with Excel 2007 and following you need to use the Ribbon to create buttons. You can also customize the Quick Access Toolbar